# sql min() in where

Tags: sql, subquery, min

I want to find those cases where an "rsp_ver" starts with 2.0 or more instead of 1.0.  I figured I could use a conditional in the where clause to find out the IDs with rsp_ver codes over "1.0" found by a subquery:

```
select 
  trim(INS.fst_name) || '  ' || Trim(INS.lst_name) as name,
  IDS.rin,
  RSP.unit_id,
  RSP.indv_id,
  RSP.rsp_id,
  RSP.rsp_sqnm,
  RSP.rsp_ver,
  cast(RSP.post_ts as char(16)) as Post,
  RSP.post_audit_id
from 
  dhsdb2.wvs_rsp RSP
  join dhsdb2.indv_name_srch INS on RSP.indv_id = INS.indv_id
  join dhsdb2.indv_demg_srch IDS on RSP.indv_id = IDS.indv_id
where 
  RSP.indv_id in 
    (select 
       SRSP.indv_id 
     from 
       dhsdb2.wvs_rsp SRSP 
     where 
       SRSP.indv_id = RSP.indv_id and
       SRSP.rsp_ver > '1.0')
  and rsp.clse_ts is null 
order by
  RSP.rsp_ver;
```

This didn't work of course.  Then I thought I needed that inner query to have the min function, but I ran int

Comment: Could you please show us your table schema?

Comment: Where does the alias `DRSP` come from? in `DRSP.indv_id`, I didn't see it in your tables?

Comment: How did the query not work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `rsp_ver` is always in the format of [Major Version].[Other Version Info], you could replace the nested select in your where clause:

```
RSP.indv_id in 
    (select 
       SRSP.indv_id 
     from 
       dhsdb2.wvs_rsp SRSP 
     where 
       SRSP.indv_id = RSP.indv_id and
       SRSP.rsp_ver > '1.0')
```

with the following:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(RSP.rsp_ver, 1, CHARINDEX('.', RSP.rsp_ver)-1) AS INT) >= 2
```

This gets the major version portion from your `rsp_var` column, converts it to an `INT`, and then returns only the rows whose major version is 2 or higher.

This has a benefit over simply casting `rsp_ver` to a numeric value when you have version numbers with more than one decimal (i.e. 2.0.1).  The downside is that it only checks the major version in its current form.

If you need to get more granular on your filtering, you could create a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that selects the different version parts from the `rsp_ver` column, along with `indv_id`, and then join on that query.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `'` from the `Where` clause in order to compare the column as a `number` rather than a string

```
select 
  trim(INS.fst_name) || '  ' || Trim(INS.lst_name) as name,
  IDS.rin,
  RSP.unit_id,
  RSP.indv_id,
  RSP.rsp_id,
  RSP.rsp_sqnm,
  RSP.rsp_ver,
  cast(RSP.post_ts as char(16)) as Post,
  RSP.post_audit_id
from 
  dhsdb2.wvs_rsp RSP
  join dhsdb2.indv_name_srch INS on RSP.indv_id = INS.indv_id
  join dhsdb2.indv_demg_srch IDS on RSP.indv_id = IDS.indv_id
where 
  RSP.indv_id in 
    (select 
       SRSP.indv_id 
     from 
       dhsdb2.wvs_rsp SRSP 
     where 
       DRSP.indv_id = RSP.indv_id and
       SRSP.rsp_ver > 1.0)
  and rsp.clse_ts is null 
order by
  RSP.rsp_ver;
```